# DIV appear/disappear on mouse enter/leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation using jQuery. I'm very new to jQuery so I'm getting a bit stuck here.

Basically what I'm trying to do is have testbutton2 appear and hide when I mouse over/off testbutton1. I was able to get this to work with mouseenter/leave.

The part I'm trying to add is to keep testbutton2 visible when I have the mouse over testbutton2 and to keep testbutton2 visible if I cursor back onto testbutton1 - so only fade in or out once.

You'll see from my code exactly what I encountered and probably have a chuckle.

**CSS**

```
#testbutton1 {
float:left;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:#69C;
}

#testbutton2 {
float:left;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:#0C6;
display:none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="testbutton1"></div>
<div id="testbutton2"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#testbutton1").on({
     mouseenter: function() {
         $("#testbutton2").fadeIn();
     },
     mouseleave: function() {
         $("#testbutton2").fadeOut();
     },

});
$("#testbutton2").on({
     mouseenter: function() {
         $("#testbutton2").fadeIn();
     },
     mouseleave: function() {
         $("#testbutton2").fadeOut();
     },

});
```

**JSFiddle**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24Yuj/)

Comment: I don't understand the scenario. Your cursor enters testbutton1, then testbutton2 becomes visible. Ok. But if your cursor leaves testbutton1 and testbutton2 would *disappear*, how could testbutton2 *remain visible* once your cursor was over it? Because in order to go over testbutton2, you have to leave testbutton1. Do testbutton1 and testbutton2 tightly touch each other, so no gap between them?

Comment: make it clear, what is expected. so that we can help you.

Comment: Picture a menu + sub menu scenario. I'm trying to create a navigation bar with sub menus. So I could cursor over menu item 1 and then submenu item 1 would appear. Cursoring into submenu item 1 would make submenu item 1 remain visible.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it in pure css.
Wrap both buttons in a larger div and show the second button only while the mouse hovers over the larger div:

```html
<div id="buttons">
    <div id="testbutton1"></div>
    <div id="testbutton2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#buttons:hover div {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r267b/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
$("#testbutton1").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $("#testbutton2").fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        var $target = $("#testbutton2");

        //delay the fade out to see whether the mouse is moved to the second button
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $target.stop(true, true).fadeOut();
        }, 200);
        $target.data('hoverTimer', timer);
    }
});
$("#testbutton2").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        //if mouse is moved inside then clear the timer so that it will not get hidden
        clearTimeout($(this).data('hoverTimer'));
        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8DR7d/)

Comment: This appears to do exactly what I needed. I tried adding a 3rd button to see if I could decipher the code and then it all broke. It's giving me a new found respect for coders everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use status variables that stores if you are hovering over button1 or over button2.

```
var isOver1 = false;
var isOver2 = false;
```

Then, add conditions to `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` in order to set hide or to alter the status variables, e.g.:

```
 mouseleave: function() {
         isOver1 = false;
         window.setTimeout( function() {
             if (!isOver2) {
                 isOver2 = false;
                 $("#testbutton2").fadeOut();
             } 
         }, 50);
```

The timeout is necessary because if you leave testbutton1, you are not entering testbutton2 at exact the same time. So waiting a bit allows to fire the testbutton2 enter event.

Here is the full demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/KTULJ/2/

Leaving button1 to button2 keeps button2, leaving back to button1 still keeps button2, leaving any button towards the space around hides button2.

With this approach, you don't need to stop an animation as it doesn't start one if it is not necessary.

Comment: If I go from button 1 to button 2 it's exactly what I needed. If I go from button 2 to button 1 it starts the fade again (which is to be expected really)

Comment: I have edited my solution :-) thx for the hint. It has now a clear float of events.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved with timers, as Arun P Johny said...

But as far as I saw, what you want to do is a menu.
Have you thought about using jQuery UI menu widget?

http://jqueryui.com/menu/